# Distinct items in a Zipfian distribution

Tags: distributions, zipf

I recently generated synthetic data sets with presumably Zipfian distribution and noticed that the frequency of the ranks doesn't change whether I generate 10^3 items or 10^6 items or a different number, assuming that I use the same alpha. I also noticed that if I generate a Zipfian distribution with the same alpha and number of items a few times, I get a similar number of distinct items every time. My question is related to frequency and distinct items in the Zipfian distribution, since so far I get the feeling that the number of distinct items for a given data set size and alpha parameter is in some close range, and cannot vary that much. Is this true and if so, is there some existing relationship between distinct items in a Zipfian distribution and the number of items N and the alpha parameter? I think this is also related to frequency of the words because if I can expect a certain number of distinct items, I could then maybe calculate a range for the frequencies of the top k items.